# Swapping buffer of stream with nullptr to simulate move?

Tags: c++, stream

I want to store a `std::istream` in a structure and be able to construct it from another stream. Currently, I have the following:

```
struct A {
    A(std::istream &in) : in_(in.rdbuf()) { }
protected:
    std::istream in_;
};
```

This only allow to create an object of type `A` from already created object, but I would like to be able to the following:

```
A(std::stringstream("hello world!"));
```

I added the following overload of `A` for rvalue-reference to `std::istream`:

```
A(std::istream &&in) : in_(in.rdbuf()) {
    in.rdbuf(nullptr); // (1)
}
```

I have added `(1)` to avoid having the buffer being destroyed after the sequence point, but I don't know if this behavior is defined or if this actually makes any sense?

Can I "move" a stream buffer like so according to the standard? If not, would this work with standard implementation and stream (`std::stringstream`, `std::fstream`, ...)?

Comment: Will `struct A` own the stream in all cases?

Comment: As for your problem, [this `rdbuf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) basically says that it's okay to not have an associated stream buffer. So it should certainly be okay to set it to a null pointer. It's not authoritative though.

Comment: @rex No - In the first case, the stream must remain alive as long next to the `A` instance (this could typically be used with `std::cin`).

Comment: If the stream was created as a shared pointer then you could store a shared pointer to the base in `struct A` i.e. `std::istream` without losing the complete object such as `std::stringstream` or `std::ifstream`. It seems to me like slicing is a risk otherwise.

Comment: So if you pass an lvalue to the constructor you want to store a reference, but if you pass an rvalue then you want to move it into `A`?

Comment: @rex kind of - I am not an expert regarding stream but as far as I know, the whole logic of stream is embedded in their buffer (eg stringstream only provide extra constructor and accessor compared to istream), but I don't know how the buffer is managed or if this is even defined...

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to avoid dealing with the buffers and to let the objects do the work for us internally.

I propose the following. With a template we can be sure to construct a shared pointer of the full type when we move a stream into the struct.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A {
    template<typename T>
    A(T& is) : is{is}
    {
        std::cout << "Only taking a reference. Not taking ownership of std::istream.\n";
    }

    template<typename T>
    A(T&& is) : own_is{std::make_unique<T>(std::move(is))}, is{*own_is}
    {
        std::cout << "using move. Not sliced.\n";
    }

    void print_stream_type()
    {
        std::cout << typeid(is).name() << '\n';
    }
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<std::istream> own_is;
    std::istream& is;
};

int main()
{
    A a1{std::stringstream{"hello world!"}};

    A a2{std::cin};

    std::ifstream ifs{"input.txt"}; 
    A a3{ifs};

    A a4{std::ifstream{"input.txt"}};

    a1.print_stream_type();
    a2.print_stream_type();
    a3.print_stream_type();
    a4.print_stream_type();

}
```

Output on MSVC2017:

```
using move. Not sliced.
Only taking a reference. Not taking ownership of std::istream.
Only taking a reference. Not taking ownership of std::istream.
using move. Not sliced.
class std::basic_stringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >
class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >
class std::basic_ifstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >
class std::basic_ifstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >
```

Also note the sequence of the members in the struct is important. The `own_is` variable will be null if `A` is constructed via a reference. But if we pass an rvalue then it will create the shared pointer first and then dereference it to pass a valid reference. In both cases the same reference points to the stream.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - `A(std::istream &)` is a better match than the template for object of type `std::istream`, but the template constructor is a better match for object of type derived from `std::istream`, e.g. `std::ifstream if; A a{if};` does not compile.

Comment: @Holt Good point. I've updated so that both constructors are templates.